# Laravel Socialite not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have a problem with using Laravel socialite, here's the code:

```
class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($provider) {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();    
    } 
    public function callback(SocialAccountService $service, $provider) {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver($provider));
        auth()->login($user, true);
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

SocialAccountService:

```
public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
{
    $providerUser = $provider->user();
    $providerName = class_basename($provider); 
    $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider($providerName)
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();
    if ($account) {
        return $account->user;
    }else{
        $account = new SocialAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => $providerName
        ]);
        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
        if (!$user) {
            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'avatar' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
            ]);
        }
        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am getting is:

> FatalThrowableError  Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in
>   /var/www/liveandnow/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php
>   on line 294

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Because I do not see any issues here with my code

error

```
(1/1) InvalidStateException 

in AbstractProvider.php (line 209)
at AbstractProvider->user()
in SocialAccountService.php (line 11)
at SocialAccountService->createOrGetUser(object(GoogleProvider))
in SocialAuthController.php (line 18)
at SocialAuthController->callback(object(SocialAccountService), 'google')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SocialAuthController), 'callback'), array(object(SocialAccountService), 'provider' => 'google'))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('callback', array(object(SocialAccountService), 'provider' => 'google'))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44)
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(SocialAuthController), 'callback')
in Route.php (line 203)
at Route->runController()
in Route.php (line 160)
at Route->run()
in Router.php (line 574)
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php (line 41)
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 65)
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `auth()->login()` you have to provide an instance of `App\User` model but instead of that, you are passing `null` value.

Here is the code you are looking for(tested):

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
        $socialMediaUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

        $user = $this->findOrCreateUser($socialMediaUser);

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->route('home');
}

public function findOrCreateUser($socialMediaUser)
{
    $user = User::where('social_provider_id', $socialMediaUser->getId())->first();

    if(is_null($user)) {
        $user = User::create([
            'social_provider_id' => $socialMediaUser->getId(),
            'name' => $socialMediaUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialMediaUser->getEmail(),
            'avatar' => $socialMediaUser->getAvatar()
        ]);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

**Complete source code:**

https://github.com/xparthxvorax/Laravel-Socialite

**Note:**

Twitter doesn't provide user's email, so this won't work for Twitter:

```
$user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
```

Comment: but my code is pretty much exactly the same, it was working before and suddenly it stopped working

Comment: then the issue might be with the social service provider which you are using? Which one are you using? In callback function print dd(Socialite::driver($provider)->user()) and show me the output.

Comment: I get something like tihs: (1/1) InvalidStateException 

in AbstractProvider.php (line 209)
at AbstractProvider->user()
in SocialAccountService.php (line 11)
at SocialAccountService->createOrGetUser(object(GoogleProvider))
in SocialAuthController.php (line 18)
at SocialAuthController->callback(object(SocialAccountService), 'google')